# Kubernetes Ingress non-root path 404 Not Found

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have the following that config that works when I try `<NodeIP>:30080`

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: app-node
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: app
          image: myregistry.net/repo/app:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          env:
            - name: NODE_ENV
              value: production
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-service
spec:
  selector:
    name: app-node
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
      nodePort: 30080
  type: NodePort
```

I am trying to use an Ingress:

```
 apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
 kind: Ingress
 metadata:
   name: nginx-ingress
 spec:
   rules:
   - host: myhost.com
     http:
       paths:
       - path: /app
         backend:
           serviceName: app-service
           servicePort: 80
```

`myhost.com` works with the nginx intro screen, but `myhost.com/app` gives `404 Not Found`. Where is the issue in my setup?

---

UPDATE:

```
   - path: /
     backend:
       serviceName: app-service
       servicePort: 80
```

If I do root path it works, but how come `/app` doesn't?

Comment: root(/) might be pointing to default backend which would be nginx welcome page, but /app might not be configured properly that,s why when routing request to that gives 404. try other url e.g myhost.com/app1 and see if nginx page shows up.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Your ingress definition creates rules that proxy traffic from the `{path}` to the `{backend.serviceName}{path}`. In your case, I believe the reason it's not working is that `/app` is proxied to `app-service:80/app` but you're intending on serving traffic at the `/` root. Try adding this annotation to your ingress resource: `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /`

Source: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/docs/examples/rewrite

Comment: If I understand correctly, yes I would like `myhost.com/app/foo => app-service:80/foo`, not `myhost.com/app/foo => app-service:80/app/foo`. That explains why my config is wrong, and why only the root config (`path: /`) works, however `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /` does not seem to point it correctly. I have also tried `ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /` with no luck.

Comment: How did you install `nginx-ingress`? Do you have manifests or instructions?

Comment: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/containers/cs_ingress.html#ingress (Step 3: Create the Ingress resource)

Comment: Ah indeed. That annotation is specific to nginx, but your ingress controller is managed by IBM (according to the docs). If you were [installing a custom nginx-ingress controller](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/containers/cs_ingress.html#user_managed) that annotation would probably work. In your case, check out the [annotation options](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/containers/cs_annotations.html#ingress_annotation). Seems like `rewrite-path` should do it instead of `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target`

Comment: I tried `ingress.bluemix.net/rewrite-path: /` as well, but it didn't work, and doesn't seem to function the same as `rewrite-target`. Confusing. Perhaps I should just consult their support, as this issue seems specific to them as a provider. I appreciate your help in pointing me towards the right direction though, thanks!

Comment: One last shot -- did you try this? https://console.bluemix.net/docs/containers/cs_annotations.html#rewrite-path

Comment: It finally works! Thank you! I had to do two things: 1. `ingress.bluemix.net/rewrite-path: "serviceName=app-service rewrite=/"` AND 2. `path: /app/` (missing trailing slash!!!).

Comment: @brandon-barnett you're a life savior. Works like charm.

Comment: In my case (on mac with docker desktop), it worked by changing annotations to the following. (in ingress yaml)
`annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx`

Answer (score 9):

As specified by brandon-barnett the issue is coming from the path but after reading the link he shared, I realised that a more specific rewrite rule would have to be specified for it to work. In my case

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: rewrite
  namespace: default
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: rewrite.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /something(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: http-svc
            port: 
              number: 80
```

The trick is with /$2 at annotation and (/|$)(.*) at the path. So what this rewrite does is that it picks everything that comes after something/ and replaces $2 with it, so:

- rewrite.bar.com/something rewrites to http-svc:80/
- rewrite.bar.com/something/ rewrites to http-svc:80/
- rewrite.bar.com/something/new rewrites to http-svc:80/new
- rewrite.bar.com/something/new/old rewrites to http-svc:80/new/old

Answer (score 4):

In case it's useful to others:

I had the same thing, and it was nothing to do with Kubernetes Ingress Nginx. It was the Nginx server in my pod running the UI (Vue.JS in my case).

**Solution**:

1. Add an nginx.conf file to my UI app.

   ```
    user  nginx;
    worker_processes  auto;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
    pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
    events {
        worker_connections  1024;
    }
    http {
        include       mime.types;
        default_type  application/octet-stream;
        sendfile        on;
        keepalive_timeout  65;
        log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                          '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                          '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
        server {
            listen       80;
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index index.html;
            location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            }
        }
    }
   ```
2. Add this line to my Dockerfile for the Vue.js app to copy the nginx.conf to your container.

   ```
    # production stage
    FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
    COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
    COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
    EXPOSE 80
    CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
   ```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54193517/4059810

Comment: Same here! But in my case ReactJs running in kubernetes. Forgot to add custom nginx.conf to my deployment

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar problem, but I have set PATHBASE in k8s yml, found out my NET8 Api didn't use the pathbase setting

In Program.cs add this

```
app.UsePathBase(builder.Configuration["PATHBASE"] ?? "/");
```

and yml like this

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapi-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapi
  template:
    metadata:
      labels: 
metadata:
  labels:
    app: myapi
spec:
  containers:
  - name: myapi
    image: my.azurecr.io/myapi
    env:
    - name: "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"
      value: "PROD"
    - name: PATHBASE  <------------
      value: "/api"  <------------
    volumeMounts:
    - name: azure-fileshare
      mountPath: /app/Uploads
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).