# Vue + Docker + Nginx app is giving 404 after refreshing the browser

Tags: javascript, docker, vue.js, nginx, nginx-config

I dockerized a Vue app using nginx and the app is running well when started. The problem comes when I refresh the page, I am getting 404 error in an image attached. I tried to configure my **nginx.conf** file like solutions from [How to use vue.js with Nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47655869/how-to-use-vue-js-with-nginx) and still get the same error. I will show my current **nginx.conf** file and **Dockerfile**.

**Error image**:
[image]

**nginx.conf** file:

```js
server {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;               
    }
}
```

**Dockerfile**:

```js
# Step 1: Build Vue Project

FROM node:14.15.1 AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# Step 2: Create Nginx Server
FROM nginx:1.20 AS prod-stage
COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to config nginx for Vue-router on Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54007569/how-to-config-nginx-for-vue-router-on-docker)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54193517/7923299. Add this to your Dockerfile and replace `[your_nginx_file.conf]`

```
# Add nginx config
COPY [your_nginx_file.conf] /temp/prod.conf
RUN envsubst /app < /temp/prod.conf > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adapt your **nginx.conf** because it is best practice not to run **port 80** inside a container.

I wrote a more detailed explanation here: [How to config nginx for Vue-router on Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54007569/how-to-config-nginx-for-vue-router-on-docker/73646200#73646200)