# Nginx Ingress controller with K8s returning 404

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, kubernetes-service

I have a service which is accepting the request at `/api/v1/orders`. I was able to validate the response using the Cluster IP. I logged into a pod and hit the `curl http://order-service/api/v1/orders` and getting the response.

I then set up a Nginx Ingress Controller and the ingress with the below yaml definition. I used the `cafe` example and the `cafe` ingress is working fine.

When I try to access my `order-service` I am getting 404. I am not sure how to debug this.

Note: My API is accessible on `http://context/api/v1/orders` endpoint. How do I redirect the path the `/orders/api/v1/orders` from the ingress?

`curl -v -H "Content-type: application/j son" -H "Accept: application/json" https://classpath.com/orders/api/v1/orders --insec ure`

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1                          
kind: Ingress                                                  
metadata:                                                      
  name: orders-microservice-ingress                            
spec:                                                          
  ingressClassName: nginx # use only with k8s version >= 1.18.0
  tls:                                                         
  - hosts:                                                     
    - classpath.com                                            
    secretName: cafe-secret                                    
  rules:                                                       
  - host: classpath.com                                        
    http:                                                      
      paths:                                                   
      - path: /orders                            
        backend:                                               
          serviceName: order-service                           
          servicePort: 80
```

I have set the aws loadbalancer IP to `classpath.com` in the `/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: How about [rewrite-target](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#rewrite-target)? Would it solve it?

Comment: I think the answer to this question [kubernetes-ingress-non-root-path-404-not-found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52021925/kubernetes-ingress-non-root-path-404-not-found/71039020#71039020) can help